# Money proof for getting Canadian visa for Iraqi citizen

Tags: visas, canada, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, iraqi-citizens

For getting Canadian Visa
How much **money** is generally required in order to be sure we are eligible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed amount. The requirements state that you must have enough money for your stay. The amount of money you will need depends on how long you will stay and if you will stay in a hotel, or with friends or relatives.
https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html